# Convert ISO 639-1 into a language name in local language with PHP

Tags: php, locale

*Stack Overflow offers some "similar" questions but none of them is suitable unfortunately. Or I am a bad searcher.*

There is the `language` column in MySQL database which stores different ISO 639-1 codes depending on the user settings. Then I grab the user's ISO 631-1 code into the `$lang` variable and can output it with `echo`. No problem.

Is there a PHP 7 compatible technique to convert `en` into English, `es` into Español, `fr` into Français, etc?

I'm currently using the following code to achieve this

```
if($lang == 'en'){$userlang = 'English';}
if($lang == 'es'){$userlang = 'Español';}
if($lang == 'fr'){$userlang = 'Français';}
```

which I don't find optimal as there is a huge list of ISO 639-1 codes and I definitely don't want to put them all into the code.

Found [locale_get_display_script](https://www.php.net/manual/locale.getdisplayscript.php) manual at php.net but it returns nothing even copypasted from a given example - may be my ISP doesn't provide all required libraries. So I can't even check if it is what I am looking for. Anyway it doesn't look like this function can get ISO 639-1 codes.

Comment: Wrong syntax! `if($lang = 'en'){$userlang = 'English';}` is always true, because you do not compare, but set $lang.

Comment: If you dont want to put them all in code, why not make a small text file that contains all these entries and parse it?

Comment: @MarkusZeller Missed = sign?

Comment: Yes, `if($lang == 'en'){$userlang = 'English';}` would be correct.

Comment: @Evert because it is the same )

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thank you! I'm just learning )

Comment: I promise you, the "PHP way" will ultimately resolve down to a file somewhere, too. Even a native way will have an OS or library file. It might be binary, but still a file somewhere. Here's a [really simple library](https://github.com/matriphe/php-iso-639) that does the work for you, and of course, it has a dedicated file. Otherwise, you can play around with the PHP International Extension but that can be weird across various platforms. For debugging purposes, I'd rather have a file to debug against.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've seen this library when was searching for the solution. I doubt I could install it at my ISP's. Also even if I could I should do that again and again when moving from one ISP to another.

Comment: @Pimpfru, it is just a data file with helper code, you can just FTP files or use composer, there's nothing to install (unless you are still talking about the PHP extension). If your host blocks you from putting PHP/CSV somewhere, I don't know what to tell you. If you can't use composer at your host, just use composer locally and FTP the files.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you for the explanation, I'll check this. But it is still not a solution (

Comment: If you go down a pure PHP/CSV path, you are guaranteed that your code should work everywhere, regardless of what your host has installed, and regardless of PHP versions (as long as the PHP is kept to simple stuff). That is the solution. You just move your code from host to host as needed, and it will keep working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found locale_get_display_script manual at php.net but it returns nothing even copypasted from a given example - may be my ISP doesn't provide all required libraries.

You can check it first before assuming that your provider doesn't support it. As far as my experience goes in PHP, if no class is installed, it will return an error, not "nothing".

```
if (!class_exists('Locale')) {
    exit ('No php_intl extension installed.');
}

$userlang = Locale::getDisplayName($lang, $lang);

var_dump($userlang);
```

If you don't have any access, even just to install packages that already support ISO 639-1 via composer, you can use this script (using `file_get_contents()`) or download [from my gist](https://gist.github.com/Kristories/f01f3d35d6ffbf3a3e2ee641b10e15e6) :

```
$codes    = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Kristories/f01f3d35d6ffbf3a3e2ee641b10e15e6/raw/d1b44ee63ff531ead9d27bc78e7815773fa706a4/ISO-639-1.json'), true);
$userlang = isset($codes[$lang]) ? $codes[$lang] : false;

var_dump($userlang);
```

Comment: It easily returns nothing if errors are disabled.